# why is my Show progress button not working?

Tags: android, button

How is my show progress button not responding because ive implemeneted a feature whereby a start and stop button should be pressed in order to count steps, calories burnt and time taken so when i press the stop button the data should be stored in a steps.db which is connected to show progress button and the button shows a diaog box of which the progress is shown on it i dont know how its not working

I tried to start and stop the buttons but when i pressed the stop button it just wasnt getting into my show progress button  i am dropping down my main fragment and stepsdatabase helper code for further info

```
package com.example.kickbits;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

import java.util.Calendar;

public class StepsDatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "steps.db";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 2;

    private static final String TABLE_WORKOUTS = "workouts";
    private static final String KEY_ID = "id";
    private static final String KEY_START_TIME = "start_time";
    private static final String KEY_END_TIME = "end_time";
    private static final String KEY_STEP_COUNT = "step_count";
    private static final String KEY_CALORIES_BURNT = "calories_burnt";
    private static final String KEY_DISTANCE = "distance";



    public StepsDatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        String CREATE_WORKOUTS_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_WORKOUTS + "("
                + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,"
                + KEY_START_TIME + " INTEGER,"
                + KEY_END_TIME + " INTEGER,"
                + KEY_STEP_COUNT + " INTEGER,"
                + KEY_CALORIES_BURNT + " FLOAT,"
                + KEY_DISTANCE + " FLOAT" + ")";
        db.execSQL(CREATE_WORKOUTS_TABLE);
    }


    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_WORKOUTS);
        onCreate(db);
    }

    public void addWorkout(WorkoutSession workout) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(KEY_START_TIME, workout.getStartTime());
        values.put(KEY_END_TIME, workout.getEndTime());
        values.put(KEY_STEP_COUNT, workout.getStepCount());
        values.put(KEY_CALORIES_BURNT, workout.getCaloriesBurnt());
        values.put(KEY_DISTANCE, workout.getDistance());
        db.insert(TABLE_WORKOUTS, null, values);
        db.close();
    }

    public WorkoutSession getWorkoutSessionForToday() {
        // Get the start of the day in milliseconds
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
        calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
        calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
        calendar.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
        long startOfDayInMillis = calendar.getTimeInMillis();

        // Get the workout session from the database where the start time is greater than or equal to the start of the day
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_WORKOUTS,
                new String[]{KEY_ID, KEY_START_TIME, KEY_END_TIME, KEY_STEP_COUNT, KEY_CALORIES_BURNT, KEY_DISTANCE},
                KEY_START_TIME + ">=?",
                new String[]{String.valueOf(startOfDayInMillis)},
                null,
                null,
                null,
                "1"); // Limit 1 to get only one result

        if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            WorkoutSession workoutSession = new WorkoutSession();
            int idIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_ID);
            int startTimeIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_START_TIME);
            int endTimeIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_END_TIME);
            int stepCountIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_STEP_COUNT);
            int caloriesBurntIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_CALORIES_BURNT);
            int distanceIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_DISTANCE);

            if (startTimeIndex != -1) workoutSession.setStartTime(cursor.getLong(startTimeIndex));
            if (endTimeIndex != -1) workoutSession.setEndTime(cursor.getLong(endTimeIndex));
            if (stepCountIndex != -1) workoutSession.setStepCount(cursor.getInt(stepCountIndex));
            if (caloriesBurntIndex != -1) workoutSession.setCaloriesBurnt(cursor.getFloat(caloriesBurntIndex));
            if (distanceIndex != -1) workoutSession.setDistance(cursor.getFloat(distanceIndex));

            cursor.close();
            return workoutSession;
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }

}
```

```
package com.example.kickbits;

import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.hardware.Sensor;
import android.hardware.SensorEvent;
import android.hardware.SensorEventListener;
import android.hardware.SensorManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.SystemClock;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;

public class MainFragment extends Fragment implements SensorEventListener {
    private SensorManager sensorManager;
    private Sensor accelerometerSensor;
    private int stepCount = 0;
    private long startTime = 0;
    private TextView stepCountTextView;
    private TextView caloriesBurntTextView;
    private TextView timeSpentWalkingTextView;
    private TextView distanceTextView;
    private TextView paceTextView;
    private Button startStopButton;
    private static final String PREFERENCES_NAME = "MyAppPreferences";
    private static final String KEY_TARGET_STEP_COUNT = "targetStepCount";
    private static final String KEY_TARGET_CALORIES = "targetCalories";

    private SharedPreferences preferences;
    private long timeElapsed = 0;
    private Handler timerHandler = new Handler();

    private static final float STEP_THRESHOLD = 1.0f;
    private static final int STEP_DELAY_MS = 300;
    private long lastStepTime = 0;
    private boolean isWorkoutStarted = false;

    private float[] lowPassFilterData = new float[3];
    private float[] gravity = new float[3];
    private float alpha = 0.8f; // Adjust this value to control the low-pass filter

    // Restored data
    private boolean isTimerRunning = false;

    private static final float AVERAGE_STRIDE_LENGTH = 0.7f; // Adjust this value based on the user's stride length
    private float totalDistanceMeters = 0.0f;
    private float totalCaloriesBurnt = 0.0f;

    private boolean isStepGoalAchieved = false;
    private boolean isCalorieGoalAchieved = false;

    private StepsDatabaseHelper stepsDatabaseHelper;


    private Runnable timerRunnable = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            timeElapsed = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() - startTime;
            updateTimerUI();
            timerHandler.postDelayed(this, 1000);
        }
    };

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);

        stepCountTextView = rootView.findViewById(R.id.stepCountTextView);
        caloriesBurntTextView = rootView.findViewById(R.id.caloriesBurntTextView);
        timeSpentWalkingTextView = rootView.findViewById(R.id.timeSpentWalkingTextView);
        startStopButton = rootView.findViewById(R.id.startStopButton);
        distanceTextView = rootView.findViewById(R.id.distanceTextView);
        paceTextView = rootView.findViewById(R.id.paceTextView);
        Button setGoalsButton = rootView.findViewById(R.id.setGoalsButton);
        preferences = getActivity().getSharedPreferences(PREFERENCES_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        stepsDatabaseHelper = new StepsDatabaseHelper(getActivity());
        Button showProgressButton = rootView.findViewById(R.id.showProgressButton);

        // Set click listener for the start/stop button
        startStopButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                toggleWorkout();
            }
        });

        setGoalsButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                showSetGoalsDialog();
            }
        });

        showProgressButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                showProgress();
            }
        });

        // Initialize the UI with the loaded data (if available)
        updateStepCountUI();
        calculateCaloriesBurnt();
        updateTimerUI();
        calculatePace();

        sensorManager = (SensorManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
        if (sensorManager != null) {
            accelerometerSensor = sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER);
        }

        return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        if (accelerometerSensor != null) {
            sensorManager.unregisterListener(this, accelerometerSensor);
        }
        if (isTimerRunning) {
            stopTimer();
            stopStepCounting();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
        if (isWorkoutStarted && event.sensor == accelerometerSensor) {
            detectSteps(event);
        }
        if (!isStepGoalAchieved && stepCount >= getTargetStepCount()) {
            isStepGoalAchieved = true;
            showGoalAchievedDialog("Step count goal achieved!");
        }
        if (!isCalorieGoalAchieved && totalCaloriesBurnt >= getTargetCalories()) {
            isCalorieGoalAchieved = true;
            showGoalAchievedDialog("Calorie burn goal achieved!");
        }
    }

    private void detectSteps(SensorEvent event) {
        // Apply low-pass filter to accelerometer data
        lowPassFilter(event);

        float[] values = lowPassFilterData;
        float x = values[0];
        float y = values[1];
        float z = values[2];

        // Calculate the magnitude of the linear acceleration
        float acceleration = (float) Math.sqrt(x * x + y * y + z * z);

        if (acceleration > STEP_THRESHOLD) {
            long currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            if (currentTime - lastStepTime > STEP_DELAY_MS) {
                lastStepTime = currentTime;
                stepCount++;
                updateStepCountUI();
                calculateCaloriesBurnt();
                calculatePace();
            }
        }
    }

    private void lowPassFilter(SensorEvent event) {
        gravity[0] = alpha * gravity[0] + (1 - alpha) * event.values[0];
        gravity[1] = alpha * gravity[1] + (1 - alpha) * event.values[1];
        gravity[2] = alpha * gravity[2] + (1 - alpha) * event.values[2];

        lowPassFilterData[0] = event.values[0] - gravity[0];
        lowPassFilterData[1] = event.values[1] - gravity[1];
        lowPassFilterData[2] = event.values[2] - gravity[2];
    }

    @Override
    public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {
        // Not used
    }

    private void updateStepCountUI() {
        // Update the step count text view
        stepCountTextView.setText("Step Count: " + stepCount);

        // Update the total distance covered during the workout
        totalDistanceMeters = stepCount * AVERAGE_STRIDE_LENGTH;

        // Display the total distance in kilometers (rounded to two decimal places)
        float distanceKilometers = totalDistanceMeters / 1000.0f;
        distanceTextView.setText("Distance: " + String.format("%.2f", distanceKilometers) + " km");


    }

    private void calculateCaloriesBurnt() {
        double userWeightKg = 70; // Replace this with the user's weight in kilograms
        double metValueWalking = 3.5; // MET value for walking

        // Calculate the time elapsed in hours
        double timeHours = timeElapsed / (1000.0 * 60 * 60);

        // Calculate the calories burnt using the MET formula
        totalCaloriesBurnt = (float) (metValueWalking * userWeightKg * timeHours);

        caloriesBurntTextView.setText("Calories Burnt: " + String.format("%.2f", totalCaloriesBurnt));
    }

    private void calculatePace() {
        // Calculate pace (distance in kilometers per hour)
        float paceKilometersPerHour = (totalDistanceMeters / (1000.0f)) / (timeElapsed / (1000.0f * 60 * 60));

        // Display the pace (rounded to two decimal places)
        paceTextView.setText("Pace: " + String.format("%.2f", paceKilometersPerHour) + " km/h");
    }

    private void toggleWorkout() {
        if (isWorkoutStarted) {
            // Stop the workout
            stopWorkout();
        } else {
            // Start the workout
            startWorkout();
        }
    }

    private void startWorkout() {
        isWorkoutStarted = true;
        startStopButton.setText("Stop Workout");
        startTime = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() - timeElapsed;

        // Reset only the timer when the workout starts
        startTimer();

        // Start step counting
        startStepCounting();

        isStepGoalAchieved = false;
        isCalorieGoalAchieved = false;
    }

    private void stopWorkout() {
        isWorkoutStarted = false;
        startStopButton.setText("Start Workout");
        stopTimer();

        WorkoutSession workout = new WorkoutSession();
        workout.setStartTime(startTime);
        workout.setEndTime(System.currentTimeMillis());
        workout.setWorkoutTime(workout.getEndTime() - workout.getStartTime());
        workout.setStepCount(stepCount);
        workout.setCaloriesBurnt(totalCaloriesBurnt);
        workout.setDistance(totalDistanceMeters);

        StepsDatabaseHelper db = new StepsDatabaseHelper(getActivity());
        db.addWorkout(workout);
    }



    private void startStepCounting() {
        if (accelerometerSensor != null) {
            sensorManager.registerListener(this, accelerometerSensor, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_UI);
        }
    }

    private void stopStepCounting() {
        if (sensorManager != null) {
            sensorManager.unregisterListener(this);
        }
    }

    private void startTimer() {
        startTime = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() - timeElapsed;
        timerHandler.postDelayed(timerRunnable, 0);
        isTimerRunning = true;
    }

    private void stopTimer() {
        timerHandler.removeCallbacks(timerRunnable);
        timeElapsed = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() - startTime;
        updateTimerUI();
        isTimerRunning = false;
    }

    private void updateTimerUI() {
        long millis = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() - startTime;
        int hours = (int) (millis / (1000 * 60 * 60));
        int minutes = (int) ((millis / (1000 * 60)) % 60);
        int seconds = (int) ((millis / 1000) % 60);
        timeSpentWalkingTextView.setText("Time Spent Walking: " + String.format("%02d:%02d:%02d", hours, minutes, seconds));
    }
    private void showSetGoalsDialog() {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
        builder.setTitle("Set Goals");

        View view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.dialog_set_goals, null);

        final EditText targetStepCountEditText = view.findViewById(R.id.targetStepCount);
        final EditText targetCaloriesEditText = view.findViewById(R.id.targetCalories);

        // Load current goals and display them in the EditTexts
        targetStepCountEditText.setText(String.valueOf(getTargetStepCount()));
        targetCaloriesEditText.setText(String.valueOf(getTargetCalories()));

        builder.setView(view);

        // Add the buttons
        builder.setPositiveButton("Save", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                // Save the goals when the user clicks "Save"
                int targetStepCount = Integer.parseInt(targetStepCountEditText.getText().toString());
                int targetCalories = Integer.parseInt(targetCaloriesEditText.getText().toString());
                setTargetStepCount(targetStepCount);
                setTargetCalories(targetCalories);
            }
        });
        builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", null);

        // Create and show the dialog
        builder.create().show();
    }
    private int getTargetStepCount() {
        return preferences.getInt(KEY_TARGET_STEP_COUNT, 0);  // Return 0 if no value is saved
    }

    private int getTargetCalories() {
        return preferences.getInt(KEY_TARGET_CALORIES, 0);  // Return 0 if no value is saved
    }

    private void setTargetStepCount(int targetStepCount) {
        preferences.edit().putInt(KEY_TARGET_STEP_COUNT, targetStepCount).apply();
    }

    private void setTargetCalories(int targetCalories) {
        preferences.edit().putInt(KEY_TARGET_CALORIES, targetCalories).apply();
    }
    private void showGoalAchievedDialog(String message) {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
        builder.setTitle("Goal Achieved");
        builder.setMessage(message);
        builder.setPositiveButton("OK", null);
        builder.create().show();
    }
    private void showProgress() {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
        builder.setTitle("Today's Progress");

        View view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.dialog_progress, null);

        TextView stepsTextView = view.findViewById(R.id.stepsTextView);
        TextView caloriesTextView = view.findViewById(R.id.caloriesTextView);
        TextView timeTextView = view.findViewById(R.id.timeTextView);
        Button previousDayButton = view.findViewById(R.id.previousDayButton);

        // Retrieve today's data from the database and display it
        WorkoutSession todayWorkout = stepsDatabaseHelper.getWorkoutSessionForToday();
        if (todayWorkout != null) {
            stepsTextView.setText("Steps: " + todayWorkout.getStepCount());
            caloriesTextView.setText("Calories: " + todayWorkout.getCaloriesBurnt());
            timeTextView.setText("Time: " + todayWorkout.getWorkoutTime());
        } else {
            stepsTextView.setText("No workout data for today");
            caloriesTextView.setText("");
            timeTextView.setText("");
        }

        previousDayButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // Open the previous day's progress screen
                Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), PreviousDayProgressActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        builder.setView(view);

        builder.setPositiveButton("Close", null);

        // Create and show the dialog
        builder.create().show();
    }

}
```

Comment: Please add only the code you seem to have an issue with!

Comment: those 2 are the only codes i seem to have an issue with because they are both connected to each other

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).